# Reply to chat message in android chat App

Tags: android, algorithm, chat

I am working on a chat app and on Reply Algorithm. Let I explain:
when someone want to reply to a specific message touches that message and on popup menu touches "Reply" then writes a message and click send. message that shows in channel is a premier message and it's reply(**LIKE TELEGRAM APP**). I don't want to send premier message again because of performance and My traffic limit in **PUBNUB** and premier message is there in client Apps. My algorithm is send premier message ID and reply then use that ID to find premier message. but App must involve a Query to find that message. I think start finding from last to first(because usually relies given to last messages) is good. questions is:

1 - all of this, is good way?

2 - there is better Query Algorithm?

this question is not for specific programming language but I am working on Android(JAVA).

Comment: some issues need to be considered, for example what if recipient has removed the premier message. or the chat containing it, has been removed altogether from recipient's app

Comment: @mangusta I tested it in telegram. when premier message deleted just reply message delivers. in my app when check for premier message and it's deleted so NULL will be return like telegram but I don't know it is good solution or not.

Comment: what else comes to mind ? this problem is not that complicated to have a variety of different solutions